# Network Manager icon is missing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, indicator, panel

A while after I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the network manager icon disappeared from the panel, although the WiFi is working. Also the Bluetooth icon disappeared too. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth can be re-added by going into the Bluetooth menu in System Settings and checking the box at the bottom that says

> Show Bluetooth status in the menu bar

Unfortunately the Network menu has no such button. I have not yet found a way to restore it on my machine, as reinstalling 'network-manager-gnome' did not help at all.